# How to pass a comparator to the constructor of a class

Tags: java, constructor, comparator

A class has the following definition:

```
public class MinPQ<Key> implements Iterable<Key> {
private Key[] pq;                    // store items at indices 1 to N
private int N;                       // number of items on priority queue
private Comparator<Key> comparator;  // optional comparator

public MinPQ(int initCapacity) {
    pq = (Key[]) new Object[initCapacity + 1];
    N = 0;
}

public MinPQ() { this(1); }

public MinPQ(int initCapacity, Comparator<Key> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
    pq = (Key[]) new Object[initCapacity + 1];
    N = 0;
}

public MinPQ(Comparator<Key> comparator) { this(1, comparator); }
........
}
```

I want to define a variable by the following statements in another class, but there is error in the last line. I wonder why and how it should be defined. Thanks!

```
class Searchnode {
    Board prebd;
    Board curbd;
    int moves;
}

class BoardComparator implements Comparator<Board> {
    public int compare(Board bd1, Board bd2) {
        if (bd1.manhattan() > bd2.manhattan())
            return 1;
        else if (bd1.manhattan() < bd2.manhattan())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

private MinPQ<Searchnode> pq = new MinPQ<Searchnode>(new BoardComparator());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from a casual glance it looks like your MinPQ is `MinPQ<Searchnode>` and your comparator is `Comparator<Board>` and your class is defined as

```
public class MinPQ<Key> implements Iterable<Key> 
{
    public MinPQ(Comparator<Key> comparator) { this(1, comparator); }
}
```

So i would expect you to have to pass a `comparator<SearchNode>` to that constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide the code for defining a comparator?

Comment: Well, its not exactly the comparator that is the issue, but the definition of the class. I would use a second generic type parameter. That looks like java? I'm not sure of the exact syntax in java, but i would expect it to be     `public class MinPQ<Key, Comp>` and then you would define a constructor with the second type as the type for the comparator.

Comment: Anybody has more comments? Please help!

Comment: If you want to use the class as-is, you have to use a 'Comparator<SearchNode>'. If you want to use a different type for the comparator, you'll either have to "hardcode" it to a specific type, or introduce a new generic type parameter to the class as i indicated in my previous comment. Other than that, what more help do you need?